# How do I add audio to getDisplayMedia?

Tags: javascript

I am making screen recorder with javascript. Here is the code:

```js
const start = document.getElementById("start");
const stop = document.getElementById("stop");
const video = document.querySelector("video");
let recorder, stream;

async function startRecording() {
  stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
    video: { mediaSource: "screen" }
  }); 

  recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

  const chunks = [];
  recorder.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data);
  recorder.onstop = e => {
     let link = document.createElement('a');
     const myValue = prompt("filename:", ".webm");
     link.download = myValue;
    const completeBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type: chunks[0].type });
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(completeBlob);
     link.href = URL.createObjectURL(completeBlob);
     link.click();
URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
   
    
  };

  recorder.start();
}

start.addEventListener("click", () => {
  start.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  stop.removeAttribute("disabled");

  startRecording();
});

stop.addEventListener("click", () => {
  stop.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  start.removeAttribute("disabled");

  recorder.stop();
  stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
 
});
```

How would I add audio to this with getDisplayMedia? I tried this:

```js
const gdmOptions = {
  video: { mediaSource: "screen" },
  audio: true
}
async function startRecording() {
  stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(gdmOptions); 
...
```

It came strait out of the MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture)

But it did not work. I am using chrome. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks and have a good day!